# Should I use past simple or present perfect here? I think both would work

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-simple

I got a call from a website

He said "I'm speaking from xyz company"

I replied
"You called for human verification?"

He said *"when"*

Maybe he thought
I'm asking "Did you call for human verification (earlier)"

Btw can we use past simple for current actions?

As far as I think in informal talks
We can use past simple for present ..

Or should I have said the whole thing

You've called for human verification?

Answer (score 1):

To make it clear you are asking a question, you could have introduced the verb 'to have' and reversed the subject and the verb:

"***Have you*** called for human verification?"

That would make it 100% clear you were asking a question. Otherwise, it just comes across as a statement and the question can only be inferred by an upward inflection of the voice.

Comment: Or "Did you call ..."